# Set default value of Symfony 2 form field in Twig

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

Is it possible to set default value of input field in Twig ?

I am rendering form row with:

```
{{ form_widget(form.title) }}
```

I want to be able to set default value like:

```
{{ form_widget(form.title, {data : 'Default title'}) }}
```

Is it even possible ?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Magic keyword for default value is `value`, not `data`.

```
{{ form_widget(form.title, {'value' : 'Default title'}) }}
```

Comment: thanks for your response :) . Is it possible to put twig variable in value like that : {{ form_widget(form.title, {value : ' {{variable_twig}} '}) }} ?

Comment: @Zagloo Simply try with:
`{{ form_widget(form.title, {value : variable_twig}) }}`

Comment: Nice ! and with text like that : {{ form_widget(form.title, {value : 'blablalbaa variable_twig  blablalblaaa'}) }}  ?

Comment: @Zagloo `'blablalbaa ' ~ variable_twig ~ ' blablalblaaa'`

Comment: `{{ form_widget(form.title, {'value' : variable_twig|number_format }) }}`

Comment: Is it also possible to set values when I render all form widgets at once?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it when creating the Type as well. I think it's "cleaner" than doing it in Twig.

Comment: You'r right, but I want to sparate backnd from using i18n mssages - I want to do it only in frontend.