# Pre-populate form value of unmapped field

Tags: symfony

I have a form that is bound to an entity, but it also has an extra unmapped field:
(from the FormType class)

```
$builder
    ->add('name')
    ->add('qoh')
    ->add('serialNumber', 'text', array('mapped' => false, 'required' => false))
```

I want to pre-populate the serialNumber field from the controller with information taken from the request URL. The closest method I have found would be:

`$form->setData(mixed $modelData)`

but the API does not specify what form '$modelData' takes and nothing I've tried has had any effect.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Someone on Symfony's IRC channel gave me this answer, and they declined to post it here:

`$form->get('serialNumber')->setData($serial_number);`

Answer (score 12):

You can use [Form Events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html). For example if you want to set the data from the database to a non mapped field you can use POST_SET_DATA:

```
class AddNonMappedDataSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
protected $em;

public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
{
    $this->em = $em;
}

public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
        FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA => 'postSetData'
    );
}

public function postSetData(FormEvent $event){
    $form = $event->getForm();
    $myEntity = $event->getData();

    if($myEntity){
        $serialNumber = $myEntity->getNumber();
        $form->get('serialNumber')->setData($serialNumber);
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can pre-populate the field in twig ([Set default value of Symfony 2 form field in Twig](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13916001/1349295)).

```
...

{{ form_widget(form.serialNumber, { value : serialNumber }) }}

...
```

Comment: Right, but the default value I want is not static, it requires some logic. I might be able to do it in Twig, but doing it in the controller would make more sense to me.

Comment: Can't this be done in just a line instead of one line per field?